# Edge on Windows 10 32-Bit blocking ajax call to localhost with Network Error 0x2efd

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, signalr, microsoft-edge

We have an app that uses SignalR to talk to scanner drivers locally that has been in production for a couple of years working on IE, Chrome and Firefox, which do not have a problem pulling down the hubs js header file for SignalR.  Once Edge came out we saw an issue with talking to localhost and after long efforts of finding a setting to allow it to communicate (and many hours with a Microsoft ticket that they found no solution), we settled on adding headers to allow Edge to grant access to domain:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:11000`

This seemed to work, but little did we notice that it worked for a 64-Bit Windows 10 Edge, but did not on 32-Bit Windows 10 Edge.  I have spent hours lowering all security settings for all zones and disabling Protected Mode, trying different ajax tricks to pull the file, but continue to get the error:

`SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.`

The following pseudo code fails:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://localhost:11000/signalr/hubs",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error:");
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

I'm looking for any insight into settings or anything else to try, or if anyone else has seen this issue.  One other piece of information, fiddler doesn't show any traffic for the call so it is being blocked by the browser it would seem.  Also on the same computer that fails with Edge - IE, Chrome and FF will succeed.

Comment: Couple of questions and things to check. First, verify `localhost` resolves to 127.0.0.1 (I've seen people who mess with the hosts file and really screw stuff up). Second, is the certificate a valid cert? Or a self-signed cert?

Comment: @dman2306 If it's working in 64 bit but not 32 bit then it can't be the hosts file due to that being a global resource. I also suggested certificates in my answer

Comment: The certificate is right as it works with the other 3 browsers.  Also the certificate is not expired.  We generate a self-signed cert at the time of install that lasts a very long time. Additionally this is not a one computer issue, it has gone through our QA team and has seen the same issue on multiple 32-bit computers, but not on multiple 64-bit computers.  It is tested with various configurations.  The issue ONLY presents itself on 32-bit Edge.  32-bit Win 7 IE and even 32-Bit Win 10 IE works.

Comment: @StevenEdison from what I've seen, Edge will reject self signed certs for cross-domain with the exact error coed you mentioned. Hence why I mentioned it. Why it's only happening in 32bit I have no idea, but I've experienced this exact issue when using self signed certs

Comment: There really is no other options.  This is an unusual situation as we are installing the certificates on client computers to have a mini server running on their computer, no one is going to sign a "localhost" cert that is distributed to over 100,000 computers (literally).  Up until this point we have had to jump through some hurdles to make things work (especially with FF), but have not seen the issue except on Edge 32-bit.  Thanks for the info dman2306, we will take that into consideration as we continue to look at the issue.

Comment: One additional thing, at install time we install the cert as trusted in the Windows Store.  We create an Authority cert and place in the trusted root and place the localhost cert in the root store.  Not sure if this makes the difference about it working with Edge 64-bit as it is pre-trusted.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem!

Comment: @StevenEdison We nearly have the same issue in our office content addin: ajax call fails on edge browser on localhost with self signed certs. Did you find a work around? We tried the call to a server with fully signed cert and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is missing the following attributes, adding which should solve the problem.

1. Request method: `GET`, `POST`, etc.
2. Request content-type (header): `application/json`, etc.
3. Request data-type (header): `json`, `XML`, etc.

Also look at the following code snippet:

```
type:"POST",
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType:"json"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it in IE compatibility mode by going into dev tools and selecting from the top drop down, if the error is still occurring with this on, chances are that it's some Windows system files that IE uses. Does this call use authentication with certificates? Maybe the certificate is out of date or Edge uses a different authentication method? Check your sources tab in IE (both compatible and non compatible) to see if the resource is being loaded, as Fiddler only captures HTTP and HTTPS traffic. That should point you in the right direction with regards to errors etc. Finally, maybe just code up a C# app that makes a request to the same URL, it's possible that the new version of .NET uses the same dependencies that could be breaking your call. If so, C# will give you enough of a descriptive error to fix the issue

Comment: IE Debugging tools has this dropdown but Edge Debugging tools does not see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31535916/1322383.  Next, how to write a C# app that does cross domains as this would require?  I can write a request, then another request, but not CORS.  I guess I could write a web app and put a breakpoint in the js and see what it says, but even that is just going to populate the same ajax event objects as Edge does.

Comment: Try it with IE 11, but if you need a Cross Origin application I'd be more than happy to help, but this type of issue doesn't really need a C# app to fix it, you just need to figure out the difference in Edge 64 bit and Edge 32 bit... Apart from the obvious :)

Comment: As noted in the post, it works on IE on the same computer (IE 11).  This is one of the things that makes it tough to understand, IE 11 pulls it's settings from Internet Options managed settings, and supposedly Edge from the same place, but IE works and Edge does not.  If it works on 3 other browsers on the same computer, and the same app works on a 64-bit Edge, it sounds like an Edge bug.  We are EXPLICITELY sending headers to say allow this communication, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. While Ajax calls to a page on the same domain were working in every other browser, in Edge they wouldn't. Opening the url used for the Ajax call in a different tab would give the correct results.
Adding the piece of code to the page serving the Ajax calls fixed it somehow... The code is in C# but maybe this will give a general idea how to fix it in other languages.

```
    if (Request.UserHostName == "127.0.0.1")
        Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Comment: Did you see I already added the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin? I can't use * wildcard because this is a banking site, and as mentioned, this fixed 64 bit but not 32 bit Edge.

Comment: Hi @StevenEdison have you figured out how to solve a problem on 32 bit Edge?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:"POST",
        data:data,
        contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(){
        //
        }
    });
```

and make sure to properly provide the parameters, content-type, data-type, responseCode..etc

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with Edge. The fix needed changes in ajax call and server running at localhost.

In ajax call I had to change from old text/plain to application/json

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

Local server was using Jersey so there I added ContainerResponseFilter implementation that adds Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods headers. Access-Control-Allow-Origin was in place already.

```
res.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
res.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
```